# How do I call a method from another controller?

Tags: c#, controller

I have a couple of reusable methods GetChartData() and GetPeopleData(). They are stored in a controller called CentralData.cs

I would like to be able to call any one of these methods from a different controller but I'm not sure how I would do that.  Does anyone know how I call a method that is located in another controller?

If the method was in the same class it would be as simple as:

```
MyMethod()
{
    GetChartData();
}
```

So if the method is in a different controller and as sucha  different class, how do I call it?

Comment: Do you want to return to ```MyMethod()``` after calling ```GetChartData()```?

Comment: Your example is not accurate enough to get a real answer : for example, we don't know if `GetChartData` has a real reason to be in a controller (it could maybe live in an external class, a static helper class, or whatever). If it needs to be in a controller, you may use inheritance, but once again, it would be usefull to be a little bit more specific.

Comment: If you need to access common functionality from multiple controllers, you should probably consider whether it's sensible to move this into a business logic layer.  If that seems like overkill, at least think about creating a single base class for your two controllers and adding your reused methods to that class.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object of `Controller` and call the function like a simple class. I do not think any problems with this approach. After all, a controller is just a class.
e.g.,

```
MyController obj = new MyController();
obj.MyFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only call a non-static method from another class if you have a reference of the object.
If you create the second controller somewhere in the first controller, like:

```
ButtonClick(object Sender, EventArgs e) {
    CentralData c = new CentralData();
}
```

you can simply save that reference in a private variable and lateron say

```
MyMethod()
{
    c.GetChartData();
}
```

If you create both of them in another class you have to pass the CentralData object to your other Controller like

```
public static void Main() {
    CentralData c = new CentralData();
    WindowController w = new WindowController(c);
}
```

or

```
public static void Main() {
    CentralData c = new CentralData();
    WindowController w = new WindowController();
    w.c = c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you have 2 controller classes: `Controller` and `OtherController`, then you can access a method located in the second class from the first class like this:

```
class Controller
{
    public void MethodA()
    {
        OtherController.MethodB(); // This will work because MethodB is static
        // Like shown above you can call a static method from anywhere
    }
}

class OtherController
{
    public static void MethodB() // <-- Notice "static"
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for and that this was a sufficient explaination. If I am too unclear, then just ask what's confusing.